# Does including glycerol in supplements make them haram?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, alcohol

If there's glycerol in a supplement, will it be considered Halal or Haram. The supplement is a bodybuilding pre-workout. Glycerol 65% (Hydromax).

I was thinking that it may be fine as I'm not going to be intoxicate or get drunk on it. I only use it before my workout and only 1 scoop.

The Original product name is: MuscleTech Anarchy, I messaged them and they told me this:

> we use HydroMax™ glycerol. This is a a three-carbon alcohol with three hydroxy (oxygen and hydrogen) groups attached, and also contains silica. Thanks!
>
> > You can learn more about HydroMax™ here: http://www.glanbianutritionals.com/products/hydromax

I approached them asking whether the glycerol used in your supplements is vegetable based or animal based, they gave me the above response.

EDIT: I forgot to mention the process of this glycerol is synthetic, not sure if it effects any of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply this general rule to medicine and supplements that include alcohol. The Fiqh rule says "Al-Darurat tobeah Al-Mahzorat" which means necessities makes the un-lawful, temporarily permissible.

This rule goes with the second rule which says "Al-darura beqadriha" which means necessities are according to their scale and duration.

In conclusion if there is no other medicine, without Alcohol, then we may take the medicine that has alcohol in it. For example, as soon as a new coughing medicine that is Alcohol-free becomes available, then we can not take the one with alcohol. 
Amount of Alcohol in the medicine is not a factor.
Allah knows better.

Comment: According to which jurisprudence or fiqh you have answered?JazakAllah

Answer (score 1):

The common usage of "alcohol" refers particularly to the *ethanol* (a *type* of alcohol) used in alcoholic beverages; this is forbidden in Islam based on its intoxicating properties.

However, the definition of alcohol used in chemistry (and as used in OP's quote) is, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol), "…any organic compound in which the hydroxyl functional group (–OH) is bound to a saturated carbon atom." This is completely distinct from its use in alcoholic beverages or as an intoxicant; most chemical alcohols, including [glycerol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol), are *not* consumed as intoxicants, and as best I can tell glycerol itself contains no notable intoxicating effect at all.

There is no evidence that the prophet *ever* forbade anything based on how its hydroxyl functional groups are bound to its carbon atoms. The only potential point of concern I see here is whether or not it's derived from animal sources, which the quoted response didn't actually clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The pharmaceutical quality gelatin used in two-piece hard-shell gelatin capsules is obtained through the processing of collagen found in the connective tissues and bones of most animals, including humans.
As above, most Glycerol (which is same as glycerine) is made from animal fats, including pig fats and bones  or waste fats which is picked from leftovers by customers at restaurants and therefore glycerol is not halal unless it specifically says that is vegetable glycerol. Most products will say `vegetable glycerol or vegetable glycerine if it is made from plants, otherwise avoid it as it will most certainly be made from animal fats and bones which is haram .